# Call JS before Rails Redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this. What I want to do is have a javascript function that shows a 'load screen' to the users. I only want this to happen for one controller though, before the redirect. That controller is like this:

Foo Controller

```
def index
  redirect_to some_path
end
```

I have it working simply by adding javascript to the whole application, but I'm not sure on how to display it only for the one controller. Usually I would be able to check the params, but it seems like the redirect hits before the javascript so I can't check it like that.

Any insight on this?

Comment: where is the javascript? how are you calling it "before the redirect"? What you are asking sounds impossible without reworking the page into a "single page application"

Answer (score 0):

The Rails redirect is actually part of the normal HTTP protocol - no data is loaded by the browser. This is why what you're asking for can't be performed BEFORE the redirect and your best approach would be to add javascript content loading to the target page.

---

The HTTP redirect goes something like this (I'm simplifying):

#### Browser:

```
GET /some/path HTTP/1.1
```

== 'can I have this web page?'

#### Server:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
Location: http://my.server.com/some/other/path
```

== 'it's over there - ask again'.

#### Browser:

```
GET /some/other/path HTTP/1.1
```

#### Server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

data
```

---

As you can see, the data is only sent AFTER the redirect.

The solution @thedarklord47 suggested is probably your only option - creating a "landing page" that will load all the resources using Javascript (similar to an SPA - single page application - probably using AJAX) instead of loading the resources like a regular web page would.

There are some good articles on the web about "perceived performance" that can give you more ideas and information.

Good Luck!